# GNU Make: wildcarding files in a stem's directory in a static pattern rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, dita

Searched a bunch, hope I didn't miss something obvious...

I have multiple book directories. Each has a single *.ditamap file (always named for the book) that references several dozen accompanying  *.dita topic files:

```
makefile

book1/
  book1.ditamap  intro.dita  topic1.dita  topic2.dita  glossary.dita

book2/
  book2.ditamap  about.dita  topicA.dita  topicB.dita  appendix.dita

book3/
  book3.ditamap  cmd1.dita  cmd2.dita cmd3.dita
```

The XHTML output (target) for a book depends on its single .ditamap file plus all the *.dita files **in that book directory** (prerequisites). The makefile is placed alongside the book directories.

Building XHTML for a book creates an output XHTML directory inside that book directory, with an index.html file that I use as the target:

```
book1/
  book1.ditamap  intro.dita  topic1.dita  topic2.dita  glossary.dita

  book1/book1_xhtml/
    index.html  ...more html and CSS files...
```

The following static pattern rule will rebuild the XHTML directory *inside* any book directory where the *.ditamap file has changed:

```
ditamap_files := $(wildcard */*.ditamap)
xhtml_files := $(patsubst %.ditamap,%_xhtml/index.html,${ditamap_files})

all: dita xhtml
dita: ${ditamap_files}
xhtml: ${xhtml_files}

${xhtml_files}: %_xhtml/index.html: %.ditamap
        dita -i "${<}" -f xhtml -o "${*}_xhtml"
```

(Side note: `make` nicely handles building the path to the index.html target thanks to its clever directory-handling rules!)

However, I haven't found a way to extend this rule to be sensitive to the *.dita files too. Whenever .ditamap **or** .dita has changed inside the book directory, the book XHTML file must be rebuilt.

I tried stuff like

```
${xhtml_files}: %_xhtml/index.html: %.ditamap $(wildcard $(dir %)/*.dita)
#                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        dita -i "${<}" -f xhtml -o "${*}_xhtml" 2>&1 | tee "${*}_xhtml.out"
```

but this completely fails to work because wildcards aren't supported in static pattern rules. Somehow I need to collect wildcarded files within the directory of the stem of each target, then make them prerequisites for that book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion), maybe:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

$(xhtml_files): %_xhtml/index.html: %.ditamap $$(wildcard $$(dir $$*)/*.dita)
    dita -i "$<" -f xhtml -o "$*_xhtml"
```

By the way, did you consider that `dita` files can change but also appear or disappear? Is this possible? If it is, what do you want to do? And do you know already how to detect this?

Comment: Yes, this worked, thank you!

I did consider the deletion aspect of DITA files. Fortunately, *.dita files do not disappear without also modifying the referencing file. And if the referencing file also disappears, then this repeats until the top-level *.ditamap file is modified (or the book is deleted entirely!).

Comment: As a slight simplification you can replace `$$(dir $$*)` with `$$(*D)`.